# pivot_wider dissolves arrange

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyr

I try to sort each row alphabetically (in order to solve this question [Reshaping a dataframe in R by sorting just some fields in a row alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143106/reshaping-a-dataframe-in-r-by-sorting-just-some-fields-in-a-row-alphabetically):

This is the dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(ALT_1 = c("GAT", "TGC", "AGC", "T"), ALT_2 = c("CAG", 
"TGA", "CGC", NA), ALT_3 = c("G", NA, "TGA", NA), ALT_4 = c("AGT", 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

  ALT_1 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_4
1   GAT   CAG     G   AGT
2   TGC   TGA  <NA>  <NA>
3   AGC   CGC   TGA  <NA>
4     T  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Expected output:

```
  ALT_1 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_4
1   AGT   CAG     G   GAT
2   TGA   TGC    NA    NA
3   AGC   CGC   TGA    NA
4     T    NA    NA    NA
```

In order to achieve this I use this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(value, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
```

and get this:

```
     id ALT_4 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_1
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 AGT   CAG   G     GAT  
2     2 NA    TGA   NA    TGC  
3     3 NA    CGC   TGA   AGC  
4     4 NA    NA    NA    T
```

I found out where the issue is:
If I stop after `pivot_longer` and use `arrange` after grouping, everything is fine like here:

[image]

But when I use `pivot_wider` to pivot back the order dissolves. like here:

[image]

The reason for this is that `names_from` argument keeps the original order where it comes from -> here `name`

**I want to know**
Is there a solution to keep the order after `pivot_wider` that was arranged by `arrange` before?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the sorting? Why is the first row resorted, but not the second row with tgc vs. tga? And am I right to assume you want to sort each row?

Comment: The logic is to sort EACH row horizontally and alphabetically. The non sorting is the failure as example after pivot_wider.  See expected output.  Yes sort each row. Thanks.

Comment: I was confused, because in your expected output, the second row is not sorted.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you deschen. Will change as soon as I am on a desktop pc.

Comment: I took the liberty and edited it.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys. You can see the result of your help here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143106/reshaping-a-dataframe-in-r-by-sorting-just-some-fields-in-a-row-alphabetically/70147005#70147005>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `pmap` to loop over the rows and `sort` with `na.last = TRUE`

```
library(purrr)
pmap_dfr(df, ~ setNames(sort(c(...), na.last =TRUE), names(df)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ALT_1 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_4
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AGT   CAG   G     GAT  
2 TGA   TGC   <NA>  <NA> 
3 AGC   CGC   TGA   <NA> 
4 T     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

---

If we want to use `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`, instead of `arrange`, use `sort` in `mutate` because `arrange` will not break the order of the 'name' column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -id
  ) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = sort(value, na.last = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  ) %>%
  select(-id)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  ALT_1 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_4
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AGT   CAG   G     GAT  
2 TGA   TGC   <NA>  <NA> 
3 AGC   CGC   TGA   <NA> 
4 T     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: In your explanation you mean `sort` will not break... and not `arrange`?

Comment: @TarJae I meant `arrange` is arranging the whole row as a unit whereas `sort` sorts the individual column separately

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something similar to the `pmap` approach with `rowwise`

```r
df <- structure(list(ALT_1 = c("GAT", "TGC", "AGC", "T"), ALT_2 = c("CAG", 
"TGA", "CGC", NA), ALT_3 = c("G", NA, "TGA", NA), ALT_4 = c("AGT", 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(c_across(everything()) %>%
    sort(na.last = TRUE) %>%
    as.data.frame.list() %>%
    setNames(names(df)))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   ALT_1 ALT_2 ALT_3 ALT_4
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 AGT   CAG   G     GAT  
#> 2 TGA   TGC   <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3 AGC   CGC   TGA   <NA> 
#> 4 T     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, yet another one:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = list(sort(c_across(everything())))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(new) %>%
  unnest_wider(new, names_repair = ~names(df))
```